# How to retrieve JSON data from HttpContent

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, json-deserialization, httpcontent

I'm buildin a console Web API to communicate with a localhost server, hosting computer games and highscores for them. Every time I run my code, I get this charming error:

> fail:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a
> parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a
> parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is
> not supported. Type 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'. Path: $ |
> LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

This is the method I'm using to post to the database. Note that this method is not in the console application. It is in the ASP.NET Core MvC application opening a web browser and listening for HTTP requests (which can come from the console application).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateHighscore(HttpContent requestContent)
{
    string jasonHs = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    HighscoreDto highscoreDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HighscoreDto>(jasonHs);

    var highscore = new Highscore()
    {
        Player = highscoreDto.Player,
        DayAchieved = highscoreDto.DayAchieved,
        Score = highscoreDto.Score,
        GameId = highscoreDto.GameId
    };

    context.Highscores.Add(highscore);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return NoContent();
}
```

I'm sending POST requests in a pure C# console application, with information gathered from user input, but the result is exactly the same when using Postman for post requests - the above *NotSupportedException*.

```
private static void AddHighscore(Highscore highscore)
{
    var jasonHighscore = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(highscore);
    Uri uri = new Uri($"{httpClient.BaseAddress}highscores");
    HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent(jasonHighscore, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, requestContent);
    if (response.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        OutputManager.ShowMessageToUser("Highscore Created");
    }
    else
    {
        OutputManager.ShowMessageToUser("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

I'm new to all this HTTP requests stuff, so if you spot some glaring errors in my code, that would be appreciated. Though, the most important question is, what am I missing, and how can I read from the HttpContent object, to be able to create a Highscore object to send to the database?

It seems to be the *string jasonHs...* line that is the problem, since the app crashed in exactly the same way, when I commented out the rest of the ActionResult method.

Comment: What line is throwing the error? Have you inspected `requestContent`? Does it in fact contain the correct JSON?

Comment: I explained it at the end, I think it's ```string jasonHs = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;``` since I commented out the other ones. I did inspect requestContent in the console app, and the JSON data was there. For some reason I can't put breakpoints into the ASP.NET solution, they don't dont work or I don't know what I'm doing!

Comment: Anyhow, I saw this article recently from Microsoft Docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client - will work through this tutorial soon. It just might contain a solution, but it looks interesting at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, we can find that you make a HTTP Post request with a json string data (serialized from a `Highscore` object) from your console client to Web API backend.

And in your action method, you create an instance of `Highscore` manually based on received data, so why not make your action accept a `Highscore` type parameter, like below. Then the [model binding system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) would help bind data to action parameter(s) automatically.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateHighscore([FromBody]Highscore highscore)
{
    //...
```

Comment: Ended up using HttpResponseMessage, instead of HttpContent in the AddHighscore method above. Worked fine, did not get the exception, I was having trouble with, when using HttpContent.